# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a 2 tables.UniversityReg & Login.When university registered to the system then General details goes to UniversityReg table & Login details goes to Login table.Using scope identity it takes last id.BUT above mentioned error shown.

UniversityReg Table

```
[UniversityId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Username] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Password] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UniversityName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[GovernmentRegNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ShortCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

Login Table

```
[LoginID] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ShortCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

SupporterReg Table

```
[SupporterId] [int] NOT NULL,
[SupporterName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[University] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ContactNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
[StudentLocation] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ImagePath] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ShortCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

To insert data i use following stored procedure,

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UniversityReg_SP]
    (
@Username varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@UniversityName varchar(50) ,
@GovernmentRegNo varchar(50) ,
@Country varchar(50) ,
@CreatedBy varchar(50)

    )
AS
DECLARE @LoginID int
INSERT INTO UniversityReg   values(@UniversityName,@GovernmentRegNo,@Country,@CreatedBy,'UNI')

SET @LoginID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Login values(@LoginID,@Username,@Password,'UNI')

RETURN
```

What is the error ? I can't see any table error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use code:

```
INSERT INTO UniversityReg(UniversityName,GovernmentRegNo,Country,CreatedBy,ShortCode)
values(@UniversityName,@GovernmentRegNo,@Country,@CreatedBy,'UNI')
```

Table `UniversityReg` has 7 columns, but in your insert you have 5 columns.

Answer (score 2):

You have too few values for your insert into UniversityReg.

N.B. that type of insert is considered bad practice - consider specifying the columns you're inserting e.g.

Instead of:

```
insert into table values(x,y,z)
```

Do:

```
insert into table (col1,col2,col3) values(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Empinfo values ('" + textBox1.Text + "''" + textBox2.Text + "''" + textBox3.Text + "''" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Insert the record");
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("e1");
            }
            finally
        {

        con.Close();

    }
    }
```